# WCF Endpoint connection fail

Tags: c#, wcf, ipc

I'm using WCF to do IPC communication between two processes.

The settings below are the endpoint settings set on the server side.

```
<services>
       <service name="IPC.Server.SessionService">
         <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/TestSessionService" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IPC.ISessionService" />
       </service>
</services>
```

And the settings below are the endpoint settings set on the client.

```
<client>
       <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/TestSessionService" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IPC.ISessionService" name="SessionServiceClient" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
</client>
```

The problem is that if the server program is started with administrator privileges, IPC communication succeeds, but if it is started with normal user privileges, endpoint connection from the client fails.

The client program has normal privileges.

I googled for a while, but couldn't find any specific information.

I checked by leaving a debug log, and the server program succeeded in creating an endpoint even with normal privileges.

In other words, the problem is that the client cannot connect to the endpoint created with normal privileges.

Thank you for help.

PS) This is the error message from client (japanese and english)

<Message=メッセージを受信できる net.pipe://localhost/TestSessionService でリッスンしているエンドポイントがありませんでした。これは一般に、アドレスまたは SOAP アクションが正しくない場合に発生します。詳細については、InnerException を参照してください (ある場合)。>

<Message=There was no endpoint listening on net.pipe://localhost/TestSessionService that could receive messages. This generally happens when the address or SOAP action is incorrect. See InnerException for details, if any. >

Comment: This error is only happened at Windows 11 Home OS and I am not sure what's wrong with Home OS.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, administrative privileges are only needed for the [HTTP URL namespace reservations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-http-and-https?redirectedfrom=MSDN). NetNamedPipeBinding does not require administrator privileges.

If not, try [WSDualHttpBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/wsdualhttpbinding) and allow the user to reach the common namespace.